# Fetch Error:Incorrect syntax near 'edrsDB'. ---> sql statement in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I want to fetch data from the database . but they said a syntax error occurs.

this is the code

```
lsCmd = "SELECT * FROM"
            lsCmd &= "(SELECT DISTINCT userid, status, DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date"
            lsCmd &= "FROM edrsDB..tbl_status"
            lsCmd &= "Union"
            lsCmd &= "SELECT DISTINCT userid, status, DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date"
            lsCmd &= "FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday"
            lsCmd &= "Union ALL"
            lsCmd &= "SELECT DISTINCT userid, status, DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date "
            lsCmd &= "FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend"
            lsCmd &= "WHERE DatePart(MM, [Date]) = 3"
            lsCmd &= "And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017"
            lsCmd &= "And date IS NOT NULL) AS monthlyRpt"
            lsCmd &= "PIVOT (MAX(status)"
            lsCmd &= "FOR userid IN (XSP, BSR, BPT, XPW, IPH, XTH, TGG, XKG, XKM, XLG, KBR, KUA, LGK,MKZ, PEN, XGM, JHB, XBN, STW, TIN, MUA)) AS pivottable"
```

they said this

> {"Fetch Error:Incorrect syntax near 'edrsDB'."}

Comment: Inspect the `lsCmd` variable in the debugger.  You should see the problem.   If you look at the string, you will see something like this in certain places:  `as DateFROM edrsDB`.  You need to add spaces in the correct places in your string to separate `Date` and `FROM` and also in other places.

Comment: oh i see there is no space between double code and statement  
i has been corrected the code by adding space..  hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution i put space after double code every lscmd="

```
lsCmd = "SELECT * FROM"
            lsCmd &= " (SELECT DISTINCT userid, status, DATEPART(dd, [date]) as Date"
            lsCmd &= " FROM edrsDB..tbl_status"
            lsCmd &= " Union"
            lsCmd &= " SELECT DISTINCT userid, status, DATEPART(DD,[date]) as Date"
            lsCmd &= " FROM edrsDB..tbl_public_holiday"
            lsCmd &= " Union ALL"
            lsCmd &= " SELECT DISTINCT userid, status, DATEPART(DD,[Date]) as Date "
            lsCmd &= " FROM edrsDB..tbl_station_weekend"
            lsCmd &= " WHERE DatePart(MM, [Date]) = 3"
            lsCmd &= " And DATEPART(YYYY, [date]) = 2017"
            lsCmd &= " And date IS NOT NULL) AS monthlyRpt"
            lsCmd &= " PIVOT (MAX(status)"
            lsCmd &= " FOR userid IN (XSP, BSR, BPT, XPW, IPH, XTH, TGG, XKG, XKM, XLG, KBR, KUA, LGK,MKZ, PEN, XGM, JHB, XBN, STW, TIN, MUA)) AS pivottable"
```